# Mongodb Distinct Query with Count

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I have a schema like below in mongodb

```
let reactions = [

  {
      messageId: 1,
      reactions: [
          {
              "userid": "7212898122",
              "reactionId": 2,
              "date": "2022-05-12T18:55:49.943Z"
          },
          {
              "userid": "8171763225",
              "reactionId": 2,
              "date": "2022-05-12T19:27:34.324Z"
          },
          {
              "userid": "8782323232",
              "reactionId": 3,
              "date": "2022-05-12T18:55:49.943Z"
          }
      ]

  },

  {
      messageId: 2,
      reactions: [
          {
              "userid": "7212898122",
              "reactionId": 1,
              "date": "2022-05-12T18:55:49.943Z"
          },
          {
              "userid": "8171763225",
              "reactionId": 2,
              "date": "2022-05-12T19:27:34.324Z"
          },
          {
              "userid": "8782323232",
              "reactionId": 1,
              "date": "2022-05-12T18:55:49.943Z"
          }
      ]

  }

]
```

I want to result like this

```
    let result = [
    {
        messageId:1,
        count:{
            2:2,
            3:1
        }
    },

    {
        messageId:1,
        count:{
            1:2,
            2:1
        }
    }
]
```

Means two user reacted on reactionId 2 and One user reacted on reactionId 1, same like that for all messageId

I tried with group, but didn't exactly get result that I want. Please answer.

===================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

1. `$unwind` to separate reactions
2. `$group` both by messageId and reactionId, to get the count you want
3. `$group` by messageId to 'revert' the `$unwind` and use `k` and `v` in the array to enable transforming into object.
4. `$project` to format as object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$reactions"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        messageId: "$messageId",
        reactionId: "$reactions.reactionId"
      },
      count: {$sum: 1}
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.messageId",
      count: {
        $push: {k: {$toString: "$_id.reactionId"}, v: "$count"}}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      messageId: "$_id",
      _id: 0,
      count: {$arrayToObject: "$count" }
    }
  }
])
```

But on mongodb the key should be string.

[playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2riKW7g71ZU)

Comment: Can please suggest to handle the case if reactions is empty in any document.

Comment: In few documents or all of them? please edit the playground link and share it, along with the expected income and I'll fix it

Comment: Few documents may contains empty reactions. https://mongoplayground.net/p/33z4lZBF1Ew

Comment: What is the expected output for messageId: 3 ?

Comment: I think it should be null. or please suggest what will be the best

Comment: How  about something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g3ndw70V_jf)?